# Shell Script - Copy the file in incremental fashion

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am looking for copying the file using shell script in incremental fashion where any file is there which is being copied from sftp (source) should not be copied to the local filesystem (destination) again.

Any way to resolve this problem statement?

Note - Source is sftp and destination is local filesystem.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: a common tool for this is [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html)

Comment: @gstukej currently the shell script that is being running is copying full files but now need to change it to increment way

Comment: @jhnc can we use rsync command on the sftp prompt ?

Comment: @RohitChawla If you want to change your shell script you should show the script in your question, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: `lftp` has built-in mirroring support, and can run over sftp. No, rsync can't run over sftp -- it has its own wire protocol.

Comment: Of course, you could also use a more powerful scripting language (like Python) with a sftp client library (paramiko) to roll your own incremental sync logic. That might have the additional benefit of problems encountered during development being unambiguously on-topic here; insofar as this is a command-line-usage question more than anything else, it's currently a bit iffy.

Comment: but will mirroring copies all the file or it will copies the file in incremental way.

Comment: lftp can absolutely do incremental mirrors. Please read the fine manual, or at least the summary page.

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow [preserves edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68435909/revisions). If you're exposing anything to the internet, and you haven't already, change your password before someone abuses it. I've flagged for mod attention to redact the revision history, but I guarantee you there's already a number of scrapers who have saved any information in there